# Good or bad & why to apply complex query in the SQL query joining?

Tags: sql

Updated 2020-09-14

I am writing a query like

```
SELECT T1.*,T2.* 
FROM T1 
LEFT OUTER JOIN 
    (A complex query which traverse entire table & returning a very big dataset) T2 ON T2.T1ID = T1.ID
```

After T2.T1ID = T1.ID, it returned a small dataset

The main reason for this question is when the bracket is removed and merge the query into one, it can be optimized.

But it required effort and it is directly proportional to the complicity of the query of T2.

The questions are:

1. For the original query with bracket, is it true that the T2 will be executed first (it executed and queried big dataset), and then joining with T1 instead.
2. If yes, is there anyway to pass filter T2.T1ID = T1.ID into the bracket so that it can query in an expected and small dataset instead of the entire table.

P.S. The SQL table is defined as plain and preliminary and without any indexing/RDBMS handling on MSSQL server

Comment: It is just a trick to either select from TA or TB. If @A = x is false there wouldn't be any rows returning from that whether it is large or small.

Comment: if @A=1 I assume the query optimizer will detect that the where clause of TB is always false and not even touch TB.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think your way of writing the query is a good idea.  In particular, the optimizer is probably going to lose information about statistics and indexes on the two tables.

I would recommend writing the code as:

```
SELECT T1.*, COALESCE(TA.VAL, TB.Val) as val
FROM T1 LEFT JOIN 
     TA 
     ON TA.T1ID = T1.ID AND @A = 1 LEFT JOIN
     TB 
     ON TB.T1ID = T1.ID AND @A = 0;
```

Answer (score 0):

The best answer to "is this bad for performance with SQL" is to try it and look at the EXPLAIN.
Nearly always, the *real* question isn't "is this bad if I have lots of rows", it's "can the query optimizer use indexes on joins and where clauses".

As you don't share DDL, or indeed the RDBMS, that's hard to define in this answer.

The answer depends very much on how smart the query optimizer is.

If T1 has an index on ID, and TA and TB have an index on T1ID, the joins would be blazing fast if you just had `outer join TA on ID=T1ID` or `outer join TB on ID=T1ID`

Your derived table, within brackets, is a trick to have the same query look at two different tables with similar columns, depending on some bit of application logic. If the query optimizer is smart enough to realize that this derived table uses tables with suitable indexes, your query should be about as fast as it's possible to be. But that's asking a lot from the query optimizer - it won't know in advance what the value of @A is.

An alternative way to do this, which is more likely to hit the indexes on the join is:

```
SELECT T1.*,TA.* 
FROM T1 
LEFT OUTER JOIN TA on T1.id = TA.T1ID
where @A = 1
UNION ALL
SELECT T1.*,TB.* 
FROM T1 
LEFT OUTER JOIN TB on T1.id = TB.T1ID
where @A = 0
```

Though again - without schema or RDBMS, it's impossible to be certain.

Comment: the SQL table is defined as plain and preliminary and without any indexing/rdbms handling on ms sql server

Comment: @SKLTFZ - Please update the question with this information. Adding indexes will have a much bigger impact than changing the query itself!